# Getting HTML source right from <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, ios

I am trying to get HTML source using the below line of code:

```
[webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"]
```

I am able to get the source. But, it is not giving me from DOCTYPE html. I want to get the complete source, from !DOCTYPE html. HTML page is being loaded dynamically in UIWebview. 
How can I get this? Please suggest.

Comment: instead of `document.documentElement.outerHTML` have you tried just `document` or `document.valueOf()`?

Comment: I tried both, but both are not giving any html source.

Comment: You can read the html as a file, instead of calling javascript, I guess it would give you the whole html as it is.

Comment: Good point, but I don't know the name of html page, HTML page is dynamically loaded in UIWebview.

Comment: Ok, I got a trick in mind, you load html in UIWebView, in the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate of UIWebView use this if(!webView.isLoading){NSString *url = [[[webview request] URL] absoluteString];} will give your url of the webview, you immediately read it as file using the url.

Comment: I am getting the url properly. When I read the content using NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlpath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
I am getting null output and the error is "Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed"

Comment: What I did is, storing the html page as file in documents directory and then use that file path to read and get the html source string.